# How do I open the developer console?

Tags: pc, titanfall

Titanfall is a Source engine game, like Half-Life 2 or Portal, so there is a developer console (~ usually) in there somewhere. Is there a command line flag or something to enable it? Or is it hidden away from users?

Comment: Might be unacsessable; I'm not sure if the source engine is adapted or not. Do other EA games have dev. consoles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source games typically have the `-console` launch option for enabling the console, however that launch option appears to be non-functional for Titanfall as well.

There is no known way of accessing the console, so the developers may have simply made it inaccessible to users.